# How to extract text in php using regex

Tags: php, regex, extract, match

My Text :

```
12a49803-713c-4204-a8e6-248e554a352d_ Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-6" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 DQrn0Ocg0dPH5MkgyszR6sjqySDl5iDH5OfoyuXq5A0KDQrH5OTaySDH5NnRyOrJIOXP2ejlySAx MDAlDQogCQkgCSAgIAkJICA= --_12a49803-713c-4204-a8e6-248e554a352d_ Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-6" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 PGh0bWw+DQo8aGVhZD4NCjxzdHlsZT48IS0tDQouaG1tZXNzYWdlIFANCnsNCm1hcmdpbjowcHg7
```

I want to extract **iso-8859-6**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

you could do: `preg_match('/charset="([^"]+)"/',$string,$m); echo $m[1];`

---

Edit: In case all need matching (prompted from other answer) modify like this:

`preg_match_all('/charset="([^"]+)"/',$string,$m); print_r($m);`

Comment: +1. But don't use the dot when there is a a more precise expression. In this case we are looking for characters which are not quotes: i.e. `"[^"]+"`. _Say what you mean and mean what you say!_ (p.s. The lazy dot is slow - the regex engine must backtrack once for each and every character. Not a problem with this particular example, but can be significant when dealing with longer texts.) Just sayin'

Comment: modified regex to please yourself, and put in single quotes so that your `"` did not need escaping.

Answer (score 4):

The regex you are looking for is:

```
iso[^"]+
```

The php code you need is:

```
<?php
$subject='12a49803-713c-4204-a8e6-248e554a352d_ Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-6" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 DQrn0Ocg0dPH5MkgyszR6sjqySDl5iDH5OfoyuXq5A0KDQrH5OTaySDH5NnRyOrJIOXP2ejlySAx MDAlDQogCQkgCSAgIAkJICA= --_12a49803-713c-4204-a8e6-248e554a352d_ Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-6" Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64 PGh0bWw+DQo8aGVhZD4NCjxzdHlsZT48IS0tDQouaG1tZXNzYWdlIFANCnsNCm1hcmdpbjowcHg7';
$pattern='/iso[^"]+/m';
if (preg_match($pattern, $subject, $match))
echo $match[0];
?>
```

The output is:

```
iso-8859-6
```

Comment: Not a good idea. If the data says `charset="utf-8"`, that regex would not work. One needs a regexp that matches whatever is between those doublequotes.

Answer (score 0):

if you are interested in getting both matches (since you have 2 in the string) and iterate through them you should do something like this.
also i used single quotes to not have to escape the quotes inside the regex. used ridgerunners suggestions aswell.

```
preg_match_all('/charset="([^"]+)"/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($result[0]); $i++) {
    # Matched text = $result[0][$i];
}
```